# How do I load plain text CSV with jQuery in IE and Chrome?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to download a CSV file to populate a graph with jQuery. Everything works fine in Firefox (12.0 win) but fails in IE (9.0 win) and Chrome (19.0 win.

> The error thrown is just "error". Nothing more.

I suspect it is due to a combination of mime-types and jQuery dataType
but I just can't get it working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**My response from the server is this: (copied from Firefox)**

```
Cache-Control:       private, s-maxage=0
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=data.csv
Content-Type:        text/plain
Date:                Mon, 21 May 2012 12:53:36 GMT
Server:              Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Transfer-Encoding:   chunked
X-AspNet-Version:    4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-Powered-By:        ASP.NET
```

**My jQuery snippet:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'dummyurl',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {

        // process

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('An error occurred: ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

(Yes, I have googled and tried a lot of suggestions :) )

Comment: Is your CSV file on the same server? You might have to ensure that the cross-domain policy isn't causing the file not to load.

Comment: Yes, it's on the same server. No cross-domain here.

Comment: Isnt `errorThrown` an object? Try inspecting it with firebug and see if you can get some more info

Comment: Oh and btw: When i was loading local xml files in IE, i needed to add `file:\\` before the path in order to make it work.

Comment: @Johan I thought so but it's just an empty string in Chrome JavaScript Console. The data is generated from a controller on the same site so I assume the http-link should work.

Comment: Nothing more useful than `statusText: "error"`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution. Here it is if someone googles for it:

Content-Type **MUST** include `charset`. If not, the request will just die with no further information in chrome.

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```